# Is there an ignore function in Racket?

Tags: function, racket, lazy-evaluation

In other words, does there exist a function `f` such that `f x` does not evaluate x and just returns void? I tried to implement something similar by using `(define (ignore x) (if true void x))` but it still evaluates x.

Comment: Racket is a strictly evaluated language, so you can’t do what you describe with a function, but you can do it with a macro. For example, something like `(define-syntax-rule (ignore x) (void))` should do what you expect. It’s a pretty useless macro, though.

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks.

Comment: Why not just remove the form alltogether if it's not supposed to be there?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
(when #f x)
```

which does not require a macro definition. This has the advantage that someone reading your code does not have to look at the definition of your macro.

Racket has the `#;` reader macro to comment out expressions; consider whether this might make sense. For instance,

```
> (+ 1 2 #;3 4)
7
```